# conversion modified guid

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have the following t-sql code which I have  converted to c#.

```
DECLARE @guidRegular UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @dtmNow DATETIME  

 SELECT @guidRegular = '{5bf8e554-8dbc-4008-9d48-5c6e0a4d28d7}'  

 SELECT @dtmNow = '2012-02-09 18:31:38' 


print (CAST(CAST(@guidRegular  AS BINARY(10))  +  CAST(@dtmNow AS BINARY(6))  AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))
```

When I execute the .net version of the code (using same Guid and DateTime) I Get a different guid? It looks like it has something to do with the datetime element can anyone help ?

c# extension code:

```
using system.data.linq;
...
...

   public static class GuidExtensions
    {
        public static Guid ToNewModifiedGuid(this Guid guid)
        {
            var dateTime = new DateTime(2012,02,09,18,31,38);
            var guidBinary = new Binary(guid.ToByteArray().Take(10).ToArray());
            var dateBinary = new Binary(BitConverter.GetBytes(dateTime.ToBinary()).ToArray().Take(6).ToArray());

            var bytes = new byte[guidBinary.Length + dateBinary.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(guidBinary.ToArray(), 0, bytes, 0, guidBinary.ToArray().Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(dateBinary.ToArray(), 0, bytes, guidBinary.ToArray().Length, dateBinary.ToArray().Length);

            return new Guid(bytes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you tacking a datetime onto a portion of a GUID instead of returning them as separate values?

Comment: The first 10 bytes of the original guid and the 6 bytes from the datetime are used to create a "modified guid" as an extension of a Guid ... var modifiedGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToModifiedGuid()

Comment: As Philip (and I) are hinting at, this is a pretty heady code smell.  Mutilating a GUID and tacking on a datetime does not make a globally unique ID more, well, globally unique.

Comment: it was indended to make the guid sequential not more unique.

Comment: I don't want to hammer you on this, but since you're holding broken code it'd make sense to refactor this beast into an identity column.  GUIDs are unique, identities are unique and sequential and, since your fingerprints will be all over the code, the next person in line won't facepalm over what you did the way you're likely facepalming over what your predecessor did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not surprised that SQL and .net would have different binary representations of a date/time.  I would be surprised if they had.

Your c# code is asking the DateTime structure to serialize a value to a 64-bit ( 8 byte) byte array that can be used to recreate the same value.  Then you're throwing away 2 bytes (the year? the millisecond? a checksum?  who knows?)

Your sql code is asking the sql engine to take it's internal representation of a datetime  - which is also 8 bytes - throw away two, and give the result.

So:

1. If you want identical values, you would need to stop relying on the internals of how a datetime is stored / serialized.   Convert it to 6 bytes using a repeatable method you can write in both .net and tsql
2. Realize that you are removing the  6 bytes of a guid that represent the spatially unique portion and replacing them with the time.  So you are creating a GUID that has the time encoded twice, and are *greatly* increasing the odds of duplicate GUIDs being created.

Of course, this ignores the more glaring issue of "why would anyone want to do that?"  I'm going to assume that it's some really brilliant subsystem, instead of the more likely explanation that somebody is desperately trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Thanks.  The sql code is from an existing app I have inherited and the comments in the code point to the following article 'The cost of guids as primary keys' http://www.informit.com/articles/article.asp?p=25862&redir=1  It sounds like the code needs replacing ......

Answer (score 0):

The original article has a flaw in the logic. The author describes both Natural and Surrogate keys but doesn't recognize that the RFC for UUIDs can be used to create a Natural key. Of course, doing so would require creating a custom function for generating a UUID based on some solution domain information, rather than relying on the default machine/time-based function for their generation.

Doing a single function to replace the generation of the keys makes a lot more sense than this, though.